# ImportError: DLL load failed: Uvedená procedura nebyla nalezena. -propably ?The specified procedure could not be found.?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to see some total basics of python image recognition. As I am tottaly newbie in this one I have found this guide:
https://medium.com/@guymodscientist/image-prediction-with-10-lines-of-code-3266f4039c7a
Installed everthing described. My thoughts are that the guide is a little bit outdated, but I have to take it...
Ending with Second.py

```
from imageai.Prediction.Custom import CustomImagePrediction
import os
execution_path = os.getcwd()
prediction = CustomImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
prediction.setModelPath("idenprof_061-0.7933.h5")
prediction.setJsonPath("idenprof_model_class.json")
prediction.loadModel(num_objects=10)

predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage("image.jpg", result_count=3)

for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
```

Running script with following result

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========================== RESTART: C:\aa\Second.py ==========================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\aa\Second.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Prediction.Custom import CustomImagePrediction
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\imageai\Prediction\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import _pywrap_utils
ImportError: DLL load failed: Uvedená procedura nebyla nalezena. -propably ?The specified procedure could not be found.?
>>>
```

Please advice to what is this error related or any tips how to make this work appreciate. Or any up-to date guide would be also nice.
I have found that it may be fixed by newer versions of python. 3.5.1 mentioned in guide seems to me quite old. But which one should I use?

Comment: It looks like a dependency/library issue, no?

Answer (score 0):

for the theory [click here](https://towardsdatascience.com/wtf-is-image-classification-8e78a8235acb), for an example on how to code one [click here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification).
The error you get is related to a missing dll, so it's a missing library that you might need to install manually, or some library did not install correctly. I recommend getting a proper tutorial on how things work, you'll understand better how everything works. Your code is basically just loading a random model from the internet, and using an image on it. The links I gave you will help you understand it better, and you'll train one yourself.